# ATX power supply doesn't cut the current after being turned off

Tags: power-supply, hardware, atx

I made a power supply for my electronic projects using a ATX power supply of a older computer and used a button connecting the black and green wires to turn it on/off.

I noticed that sometimes when I turn it off, the power supply didn't cut the current and still keeps the circuit operating. I have to remove the power cable of the power supply.
Actually when I don't apply any charge to the power supply it turns off normally, but after I put some load it still operates when the button turn off is pressed.

complete schematic:

[image]

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: So, you say a button, but it should be a switch that grounds the green wire to keep it on, and disconnect to turn it off. What kind of button it is? Do you have a 4k7 pull-up on the green wire to purple 5VSB line?

Comment: are you connecting to the non-switchable power pin?

Comment: I only have:
10ohm/10J resistor between red and black.
led in serie with a resistor to the indicate Standby,
led in serie with a resistor to the indicate Power on,
and Button Switch on/off between green and  black

Comment: what pin number is brown?

Comment: Your green wire needs a 2.2K to 4.7K pull-up resistor to a voltage that matches its OFF state voltage, possibly 3.3 volts. Not all old PSU's will have internal pull-ups.

Comment: didn't understand the connection of the pull-up resistor. could you guys draw it?

Comment: @BrunoPimenta connect one end of the resistor to the green wire and the other end to the purple wire.